# Function With CASE statement compilation error

Tags: plsql

Good afternoon,
Within Oracle apex i'm trying to create a simple function with a case statement in-bedded within it.

My issue arises when I try create my function I encounter a compilation error, below is the code used:

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sale( empid NUMBER)
 RETURN NUMBER IS
 empid NUMBER;
 BEGIN

 SELECT( CASE
 WHEN sales >  0 AND sales <= 700 THEN 'low'
 WHEN sales >= 701 AND sales <= 1200 THEN 'med'
 WHEN sales > 1201  THEN 'high'
 ELSE 'N/A'
 END) AS tot_sales

 FROM emps
 WHERE emps.empid = sale.empid;
 RETURN ( 'employee: ' || empid || ' has a ' || tot_sales|| 'rating of total sales');

 END;
 /
```

When ran the compilation is unsuccessful.

Help please

Comment: Whenever you're asking about an error, it's extremely helpful to post the text of the error.

Comment: PLS-00410: duplicate fields in RECORD,TABLE or argument list are 
     not permitted

Comment: I'm dumb, I see the error has to do with my declaration in line 1. How would I fix this and avoid using the empid twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sale( v_empid NUMBER)
RETURN varchar2 IS
v_text varchar2(200);
BEGIN

SELECT CASE
WHEN sales >  0 AND sales <= 700 THEN 'low'
WHEN sales >= 701 AND sales <= 1200 THEN 'med'
WHEN sales > 1201  THEN 'high'
ELSE 'N/A'
END 
into v_text
FROM emps
WHERE emps.empid = v_empid;
RETURN ( 'employee: ' || v_empid || ' has a ' || v_text|| ' rating of total 
sales');
END;
```

try this.
you need to declare string variable  and result from your query should put into it.
But also consider that your query should return only one row. Otherwise you'll get error.
And parameter name must be different from column name as well.

Comment: The function you shared is valid, however when it comes to testing the function; using a selected empid from my emps table oracle produces:  `ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error`

Comment: I've updated script. you should return VARCHAR2 type from function if you want to get text.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a SQL SELECT statement within in PL/SQL - between the BEGIN and the END keywords - you must select INTO something so that PL/SQL can utilize a variable to hold your result from the query. It is important to note here that if you are selecting multiple columns, you must specify multiple variables or a record to insert the results of your query into.

For example:

```
SELECT 1 
INTO v_dummy
FROM dual;
```

or:

```
SELECT 1,2
INTO v_dummy
FROM dual;
```

If you are expecting your query to return multiple rows, this will not be possible in a select into query. You should only expect to receive 1 row of data when using this.

You will also need to declare your variable that you are selecting into.